# @JsonCreator annotation want an enum value for attribute mode, but is allready given

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jackson, fasterxml

When creating a shared library for automated deployment with jenkins I use a rest service that provides me with Json objects. Now when I run the pipeline the following error occurs:

`Expected enum Value for attribute mode in @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator`

The interesting thing is that this error does not occur on another Jenkins instance.

The code:

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Asset {
    final String downloadUrl
    final String path
    final String repository
    final String format


    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    Asset(
        @JsonProperty('downloadUrl') String downloadUrl,
        @JsonProperty('path') String path,
        @JsonProperty('repository') String repository,
        @JsonProperty('format') String format
    ){
        this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl
        this.path = path
        this.repository = repository
        this.format = format
    }


    @Override @NonCPS
    String toString() {
        return "Asset{" +
            "downloadUrl='" + downloadUrl + '\'' +
            ", path='" + path + '\'' +
            ", repository='" + repository + '\'' +
            ", format='" + format + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```